# Finding largest cylinder to be placed in a sphere of a given radius

Tags: math, volume, differentiation

Take both volumes, viz.: pi r^2 h to be < 4/3 pi a^3,
to distinguish between radii of the 2 figures, let us call the radius of the sphere a

pi is divided out

r^2 h < 4/3 a^3

It is time to take the derivate in order to find the maximal r, but the 4/3 a^3 in case of differentiating on r, is a constant, and is lost in the derivative. With thus all useful info is lost. But I see no way to retain the constant in the derivative. Or is there a cleverer way? thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Pity the question is off-topic and I can hence not tell you to calculate cylinder radius from h and differentiate then.... ;-)

Comment: Your inequality reflects the obvious fact that contained object  has smaller volume than container. Differentiating both parts of this inequality (by different variables) makes no sense.